# Trying to add group to the security tab of an extended right

Tags: active-directory, powershell

. The only problem is that the rights are not propagating to the extended attribute, even in the advanced tab :(.

If  I go in to adsi and check the security tab of the extended right it shows nothing regarding the new group having rights... but ... If I check the variable $rootObjACL.access, it shows the rights as they should be.

```
ActiveDirectoryRights : ExtendedRight
InheritanceType       : None
ObjectType            : 1131f6aa-9c07-11d1-f79f-00c04fc2dcd2
InheritedObjectType   : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ObjectFlags           : ObjectAceTypePresent
AccessControlType     : Allow
IdentityReference     : NEW\Replication
IsInherited           : False
InheritanceFlags      : None
PropagationFlags      : None**
```

Trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.  There are no errors what so ever while running the script. Here is the script below.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$rootObjPath = "AD:\CN=Configuration,DC=new,DC=domain,DC=com"

$rootObjACL = Get-Acl $rootObjPath

$group = Get-ADgroup 'Replication'

$SID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifierArgumentList $group.SID

# The following object specific ACE is to grant Group the permission     DS-Replication-Get-Changes

$objectGuid = New-Object Guid 1131f6aa-9c07-11d1-f79f-00c04fc2dcd2

$ADRight = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights]"ExtendedRight"

$ACEType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]"Allow"

$ACE = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule -ArgumentList $SID,$ADRight,$ACEType,$objectGuid

$rootObjACL.AddAccessRule($ACE)



Set-Acl $rootObjPath -AclObject $rootObjACL
```

Comment: You need to add more details

Comment: @JimB  I added additional info in the top message.

Comment: I think this has the makings to be a good question. Instead of referencing back to something else include what you're trying to accomplish and what you're starting with.

Comment: @ScottPack agreed - sticking in a link doesn't cut it, so it should be closed

Comment: @JimB As it stands, yes, but I see some potential here so I wanted to give it a chance to get awesome first.

Comment: Actually it was not me who edited the post .. I did remove the link.  I ended up using the dell cmdlet and it worked like a charm.

Comment: add-QADpermission 'CN=Configuration,DC=new,DC=domain,DC=com' -account 'new\replication' -rights ExtendedRight -ExtendedRIght ‘DS-Replication-Get-Changes’